# How do you duplicate rows based on a quantity in a cell? LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

I have an Orders table and an Assignments table which I join together using LINQ to Entities.  Each order has a product and a quantity.  Each order has a number of assignments up to the quantity.  I want to output the following:

Orders:

```
ID | OrderCode | Quantity | Other Columns...
1  | 30000-1   | 3        | ...
2  | 41000-7   | 2        | ...
```

Assignments:

```
OrderID | Assignment | Other Columns...
1       | 4526       | ...
2       | 2661       | ...
2       | 5412       | ...
```

I want to output a table like:

```
OrderCode | Assignment
30000-1   | 4526
30000-1   | 
30000-1   |
41000-7   | 2661
41000-7   | 5412
```

Any advice would be welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would split the task up into three parts.

First, I'd use LINQ to Entities to get the full collection of orders, each with it's  corresponding collection of assignments:

```
var a = (from o in orders
         join a in assignments on s.Id equals a.OrderId into oa
         //Notice that I use oa.DefaultIfEmpty().  This essentially the way to do a
         //LEFT JOIN in LINQ.  You'll want to do a LEFT JOIN if you don't
         //want to exclude order codes that have no assignments
         select new { o.OrderCode, o.Quantity, Assignments = oa.DefaultIfEmpty() })
        .ToList();
```

`a` returns the following for your example:

```
OrderCode | Assignment
30000-1   | 4526
41000-7   | 2661
41000-7   | 5412
```

Then I'd add the "missing" rows

```
var b = a.SelectMany(o => 
{
    var numOrdersInList = o.Count(o2 => o2.OrderCode == o.OrderCode);
    return Enumerable.Range(0, o.Quantity - numOrdersInList)
                     .Select(i => new 
                                 { 
                                     o.OrderCode, 
                                     Assignment = Enumerable.Empty<Assignment>() 
                                 });
});
```

`b` returns the following for your example:

```
OrderCode | Assignment
30000-1   | 
30000-1   |
```

Then I'd concat the two enumerables.

```
var c = a.Select(o => new { o.OrderCode, o.Assignment })
         .Concat(b);
```

Finally, the concatenation should return what you expect for your example:

```
OrderCode | Assignment
30000-1   | 4526
30000-1   | 
30000-1   |
41000-7   | 2661
41000-7   | 5412
```